# Is Pleinair playable in Disgaea D2 English Release

Tags: disgaea-d2

looking over the DLC Release Schedule from NISA doesn't show Pleinair as being a DLC character however her profile on the wiki shows a D2 cut-in image but no info on how she is unlocked as playable (if she is, cut-in can also be used for enemies) or if she is DLC only for the Japanese version

so i am wondering, Is Pleinair playable in the English release of Disgaea D2: A Brighter Darkness and if so how

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Pleinair wikia page](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Pleinair), she is not a playable character in Disgaea D2. In fact,

> Disgaea D2 is currently the ***only*** game without a playable Pleinair. Strangely, she has a unique Evility called "Acceleration Movement" and stats coded into the game but there is no possible way of obtaining her Evility, or recruiting her since she is not a DLC character nor an in-game recruitable character.